# Close Python subprocess.PIPE after process is terminated

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am using Python 2.7.8 to coordinate and automate the running of several application many times over in a Windows environment. During each run, I use `subprocess.Popen` to launch several child process, passing `subprocess.PIPE` for `stdin` and `stdout` to each as follows:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

where `cmd` is the list of arguments.

The script waits for an external trigger to know when a given run is done, and then terminates each application it is currently running by writing a string to the `stdin` of each `Popen` object. The applications read this string, and perform its own graceful shutdown (which is why I don't simply call `kill()` or `terminate()`).

```
# Try to shutdown process
timeout = 5
try:
   if proc.poll() is None:
      proc.stdin.write(cmd)

      # Wait to see if proc shuts down gracefully
      while timeout > 0:
         if proc.poll() is not None:
            break
         else:
            time.sleep(1)
            timeout -= 1
      else:
         # Kill it the old fashioned way
         proc.kill()
except Error:
   pass   # Process as necessary...
```

Once the applications are complete, I'm left with a `Popen` object. If I inspect the `stdin` or `stdout` members of that object, I get something like the following:

```
<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'wb' at 0x0277C758>
```

The script then loops to perform the next run, relaunching the necessary applications.

My question is, do I need to explicitly call `close()` for the `stdin` and `stdout` file descriptors each time, in order to avoid leaks, i.e. in the `finally` statement above? I am wondering this because it is possible for the loop to occur hundreds, or even thousands of times during a given script.

I've looked through the subprocess.py code, but the file handles for the pipes are created by an apparent Windows(-only) call in the `_subprocess` module, so I can't get any further detail.

Comment: how are you running the commands?

Comment: the subprocess communicate method call close. if you don't use communicate, you should call close, just to be safe.

Comment: unrelated: don't use `stdout=PIPE` unless you read from the pipe otherwise a deadlock is possible if the child process generates enough output.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Agreed...I did not include the code that I use to read from stdout, for simplicity. I have it read out in a separate thread for debugging, for now. The `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` will be removed eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipes might eventually be closed during the garbage collection but you should not rely on it and close the pipes explicitly.

```
def kill_process(process):
    if process.poll() is None: # don't send the signal unless it seems it is necessary
        try:
            process.kill()
        except OSError: # ignore
            pass

# shutdown process in `timeout` seconds
t = Timer(timeout, kill_process, [proc])
t.start()
proc.communicate(cmd)
t.cancel()
```

`.communicate()` method closes the pipes and waits for the child process to exit.